# Vercel - Showing 404 Page Not Found When Deploying Vite SSR

Tags: reactjs, vite, server-side-rendering, vercel

I just tried deploying my Vite SSR React project, the build ran successfully but when it came to the deployment I ran into and issue. Here, take a look:

[image: 404 Page Not Found]

It runs fine on my local machine when I use the `npm run dev` or `npm run build` and then `npm run preview`

I am having a feeling that the issue might be from the Vercel deployment setting but I can't wrap my head around it.

[image]

I tried overriding the `Development Comand` to `npm run preview` but it didn't work.

Comment: There is a possibility that the output build directory is not the same as the vercel default `dist`. When you build your project your generated bundle directory is `dist` or `.next`?

Comment: Yes, when building locally it was in a dist directory. So that's why I'm lost.

Comment: I think you need to Override your Development command to `npm run build` or what is the equivalent of the build command you are using. Using `npm run preview` just runs the generated bundle and it won't work

Comment: I thought the `npm run build` is only needed when building the project then the `npm run preview` should be for the development build. How can i go about setting things up?

Comment: I made a mistake on my previous comment, sorry.  I think you should override all settings and add your scripts, even tho they are the same as the default settings and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue was on the `Output Directory`, the default directory was set to `dist` but my build was `dist/client/`. All I needed to do was to edit the vercel output directory to match the `dist/client/` path.